# Mysql scrip for delete all row where there is a zero in every existig table

Tags: mysql, event-handling

I have an event checking for 3 table to delete a row when the quality is lower than 50 but now i want to change it so that it check for every table automatically in the same database without always need to repeat the same line like in my code below

```
DELIMITER |
/* vervang ALTER naar CREATE voor een nieuw event*/
ALTER EVENT removezero
    ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 Hour STARTS '2017-10-30 10:00:00' ON COMPLETION PRESERVE ENABLE
    DO
        Begin
        DELETE FROM kepserverex.plc1 WHERE BelgischePLC_PLC_1_WasCyclus_QUALITY < 50;
        DELETE FROM kepserverex.plc2 WHERE BelgischePLC_PLC_2_WasCyclus_QUALITY < 50;
        DELETE FROM kepserverex.plc3 WHERE BelgischePLC_PLC_3_WasCyclus_QUALITY < 50;
        END|
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Please format your post.

Comment: Within a loop reference information_schema,tables to find all tables with the same name pattern, generate dynamic sql code and execute it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check This out it will give you all the queries you need to excute then CREATE a PROCEDURE to excute it..

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(t.query SEPARATOR '; ')
FROM
(
    SELECT CONCAT('DELETE FROM ', a.table_name,
                  ' WHERE BelgischePLC_PLC_1_WasCyclus_QUALITY < 50;') AS query,
        '1' AS id
    FROM information_schema.tables a
    WHERE a.table_schema = 'kepserverex'
) t
GROUP BY t.id
```

**EDIT :** 
As @P.Salmon comment if you have too many tables you may reach the max lengh of goupe_concat. you can make it begger by changing it in the config file or just iusing this query `SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 1000000;` 
Or print the result line by line

```
USE INFORMATION_SCHEMA;
SELECT CONCAT("DELETE FROM `", TABLE_SCHEMA,"`.`", TABLE_NAME, "` WHERE BelgischePLC_PLC_1_WasCyclus_QUALITY < 50;") 
AS MySQLCMD FROM TABLES 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = "kepserverex";
```

**NB:** The one without the Group_concat it return rows so you have to use `Cursor` to iterate through a set of rows

Store the result into sql file then excute it; I am using hours in the file name because you said you will excute the event each hour, otherwise you will have to delte the file if you want to use the same name or tell mysql to overwrite it

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(t.query SEPARATOR '; ') INTO OUTFILE '/var/lib/mysql-files/hour(now())alterstatements.sql'
FROM
(
    SELECT CONCAT('DELETE FROM ', a.table_name,
                  ' WHERE BelgischePLC_PLC_1_WasCyclus_QUALITY < 50') AS query,
        '1' AS id
    FROM information_schema.tables a
    WHERE a.table_schema = 'db_lists'
) t
GROUP BY t.id;

Source '/var/lib/mysql-files/hour(now())alterstatements.sql';
```

Comment: OP doesn't say how many tables there may be so this could burst the group_concat default limit.

Comment: i try the last edit and it works fine like i want but now I'm stuck in execution. I try this : PREPARE stmt1 FROM @output; 
EXECUTE stmt1; 
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;

Comment: @MichielMaes Check The last Edit.

Comment: @AnouarZBAIDA  i try it but Mysql give me a error : 1064

Comment: Full error : 14:38:42 PREPARE stmt FROM @MySQLCMD Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELETE FROM test1 WHERE WHERE QUALITY < 50' at line 1 0.000 sec

Comment: @MichielMaes there is two Where in the error.. now it is clear you delete one of the 'where' in the query

Comment: i removed it and i get the same error number but in the end he does something strange : 
14:57:44 PREPARE stmt FROM @MySQLCMD Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELETE FROM plc1 WHERE BelgischePLC_PLC_1_WasCyclus_QUALITY < 50; DELETE FROM pl' at line 1 0.000 sec

Comment: Me too - I don't think you can execute multiple statements in a prepared statement.

Comment: yup @P.Salmon that's what i found out, I am still looking if there is a workout to it without using cursor in a procedure

Comment: You can if you keep your string and parse each delete out in a loop with prepared statements (in a stored program)

Comment: I am thinking of something with the 2nd code to write to a temporary table and then execute everything 1 by 1. or is such a solution not a good idea?

Comment: @MichielMaes check the last edit otherwise do it with  a stored procedure and use cursor.

Comment: again a error :s i gone try with the cursor thanks for your help and time

Answer (score 0):

In this example I have set up a procedure illustrate how to do this but you should be able to lift and drop the code within the procedure to an event.

```
truncate table plc1;
truncate table plc2;
truncate table plc3;
insert into plc1 (BelgischePLC_PLC_1_WasCyclus_QUALITY) values (10),(40),(50);
insert into plc2 (BelgischePLC_PLC_2_WasCyclus_QUALITY) values (10),(40),(50);
insert into plc3 (BelgischePLC_PLC_3_WasCyclus_QUALITY) values (10),(40),(50);
select 'p1 before', p.* from plc1 p;
select 'p2 before', p.* from plc2 p;
select 'p3 before', p.* from plc3 p;

drop procedure if exists t;

delimiter $$
create procedure t ()
begin
set @stmt = null;
#Parse information schema table and columns to build a big string
set @str = (select group_concat(str)
from
(
select concat('delete from ' , it.table_schema , '.', it.TABLE_NAME , ' where ' , ic.column_name , ' < 50;') str
from information_schema.`TABLES` it
join information_schema.columns ic on ic.table_name = it.table_name
where it.table_name like 'plc%'
        and ic.column_name like '%plc%'
) s
);
set @str = replace(@str,';,',';'); #tidy up
#parse the big string and execute prepared statement
while length(@str) > 0 do
set @stmt = substring(@str,1,instr(@str,';'));
set @str = replace(@str, @stmt,'');
#select 'stmt ', @stmt;
prepare stmt from @stmt;
execute stmt;
deallocate prepare stmt;

end while;

end $$

delimiter ;

call t();
select 'p1 after', p.* from plc1 p;
select 'p2 after', p.* from plc2 p;
select 'p3 after', p.* from plc3 p;
```

result

```
MariaDB [sandbox]> select 'p1 after', p.* from plc1 p;
+----------+----+--------------------------------------+
| p1 after | id | BelgischePLC_PLC_1_WasCyclus_QUALITY |
+----------+----+--------------------------------------+
| p1 after |  3 |                                   50 |
+----------+----+--------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> select 'p2 after', p.* from plc2 p;
+----------+----+--------------------------------------+
| p2 after | id | BelgischePLC_PLC_2_WasCyclus_QUALITY |
+----------+----+--------------------------------------+
| p2 after |  3 |                                   50 |
+----------+----+--------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> select 'p3 after', p.* from plc3 p;
+----------+----+--------------------------------------+
| p3 after | id | BelgischePLC_PLC_3_WasCyclus_QUALITY |
+----------+----+--------------------------------------+
| p3 after |  3 |                                   50 |
+----------+----+--------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```